# Include assets javascript coffee to view partial on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Pretty basic question here:

I on rails 3.2.17, need to include some coffeescript to my application, would rather not add it to my views.

my views folder is named episodes and would like to connect partial _show_info.html.erb to assets/javascript/episodes.js.coffee

just need the proper javascript include tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to add it to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and have it added to the Asset Pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend adding this to your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file:

```
//= require episodes
```

That way, you'll have access to it everywhere, and when you push to production, it'll be minified and concatenated with all the rest of your JavaScripts. You can read up on the asset pipeline [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). Especially check out the [section on JavaScript Compression](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-compression).